# Laravel 6 - `Undefined variable: value` only error in the first time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

In the first time I want to save data to database from table this error appear.

> ErrorException
>       Undefined variable: value

so I have to manually input the data from `tinker` or `mysql`

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)

{

    $validateData = $request->validate([

        'name_device_type' => 'required|max:255',

        'signature' => 'Nullable'

    ]);



    $id = DeviceType::getidDeviceTypes();

    foreach ($id as $value);   // Error happend in this line.

    $lastdevicetypeId = $value->id;

    $newdevicetypeId = $lastdevicetypeId + 1;

    $GetnewdevicetypeId = sprintf('DT%04d', $newdevicetypeId);



    $devicetypes = new DeviceType();

    $devicetypes->idDeviceType = $GetnewdevicetypeId;

    $devicetypes->name_device_type = $request->input('name_device_type');

    $devicetypes->signature = $request->input('signature');

    $devicetypes->save();



    return redirect('/devicetypes')->with('success', 'New Device Type is added');

}
```

My Migration table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('device_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('idDeviceType');
            $table->string('name_device_type');
            $table->mediumText('signature');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My create.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'DeviceTypesController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('name_device_type', 'Type Device'); !!}
            {!! Form::text('name_device_type', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Type Device']); !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('signature', 'Signature (Optional)'); !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('signature', '', ['id' => 'classic-ckeditor5', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Signature']); !!}
        </div>
        {{ Form::button('<i class="far fa-save"></i> Submit', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-info'] )  }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

the Model

```
class DeviceType extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'device_types';
    // Primary Key
    protected $primaryKey = 'idDeviceTypes';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    public $incrementing = false;

    public static function getidDeviceType(){
        return $getidDeviceType = DB::table('device_types')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(1)->get();
    }
}
```

But if the table has data this error disappear, also this error will appear again if I remove every data and made the table empty.

Comment: check whether `$id = DeviceType::getidDeviceTypes();` has count. So wrap the code in `if(isset($id) && count($id)>0) {  // place here foreach loop code and even use curly bracket for foreach code that will make more clear }`

Comment: `foreach ($id as $value);` - you terminate the loop (see the `;` at the end there, and no brackets `{ }`)- meaning that it has no content to execute within each iteration.

Comment: @Qirel the semicolon does not terminate the loop, it is still iterating and assiging a value to `$value` ... its just that the loop isn't running because they have no records to iterate over

Comment: @lagbox What makes you think there are no records?

Comment: It terminates the *line*, to be more precise then, so, as I said, there's no content to be executed for each iteration. Point still remains.

Comment: @Daedalus "But if the table has data this error disappear, also this error will appear again if I remove every data and made the table empty." "In the first time I want to save data to database from table this error appear ... so I have to manually input the data from tinker or mysql"

Comment: @lagbox Your quote contains the text "so I have to manually input the data from tinker or mysql", meaning data may or may not exist prior to the test.

Comment: after they add data it works because the loop runs and there is a `$value` variable ... when there are no records (empty table - "first time") there is nothing to iterate over so there is never a `$value` variable created

Comment: @lagbox Good point; should I delete my comments or leave them?

Comment: @Daedalus one of those ones where some more information from the OP would help ... it could be just wanting to get the last record for something particular then that loop technically does that ... or it could be that a chunk of that code belongs in the loop and that loop is meant to run over each item which would be typo/structural issue

Comment: @Aditya is this supposed to be only creating 1 new record or numerous records depending on how many items are returned from `DeviceType::getidDeviceTypes()`?

Comment: @lagbox this is supposed to creating 1 record, so the plan is to put the `$id` in the `$idDeviceType` when $id=1 then the $idDeviceType=DT0001

Comment: so the first one would be `DT0001` ?

Comment: @lagbox yeah that's the plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the max 'id' of the table and add 1 to it without having to grab a whole record:

```
...
// validation

$newdevicetypeId = DeviceType::max('id') + 1;

$GetnewdevicetypeId = sprintf('DT%04d', $newdevicetypeId);

// new DeviceType
...
```

There is the option of having a model event that can set this particular field after the record has been created so it has its own id to use.

Comment: `$id` is the `bigincrement` Laravel have by default when creating migration table I didn't change that.

Comment: is `DeviceType::getidDeviceTypes()` returning an array or collection?

Comment: there is still one issue with this code, that it always return `DT0001`.

Comment: show the `getidDeviceTypes` method of the `DeviceType` model

Comment: i add it check the question

Comment: Its working now :), thank you so much you spend so much time to answer this basic question.

Answer (score 3):

You have a Semicolon right after the `foreach` loop definition: `foreach ($id as $value);` 
and you are using the `$value` in the next line `$lastdevicetypeId = $value->id;` which is outside the scope of your loop.

You should remove the `;` following the the `foreach` loop and change it to `:` and add a `endforeach;` where you want to end the loop.

Example:

```
foreach ($id as $value):
    $lastdevicetypeId = $value->id;
    $newdevicetypeId = $lastdevicetypeId + 1;
    $GetnewdevicetypeId = sprintf('DT%04d', $newdevicetypeId);

    $devicetypes = new DeviceType();
    $devicetypes->idDeviceType = $GetnewdevicetypeId;
    $devicetypes->name_device_type = $request->input('name_device_type');
    $devicetypes->signature = $request->input('signature');
    $devicetypes->save();
endforeach;
```

Or you can write this code as:

```
foreach ($id as $value){
    $lastdevicetypeId = $value->id;
    $newdevicetypeId = $lastdevicetypeId + 1;
    $GetnewdevicetypeId = sprintf('DT%04d', $newdevicetypeId);

    $devicetypes = new DeviceType();
    $devicetypes->idDeviceType = $GetnewdevicetypeId;
    $devicetypes->name_device_type = $request->input('name_device_type');
    $devicetypes->signature = $request->input('signature');
    $devicetypes->save();
}
```

Comment: Your answer does remove the error message, but I'm having new issue the data isn't saved to the database.

Comment: Does the `$id` variable even has a collection or an array? Have you checked it? If not try `dd($id)` just before the `foreach` loop. If its empty, then you should check the `DeviceType::getidDeviceTypes()` to see why it is not returning any data.