# Laravel 6 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

to migrate this `Schema`

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('transaction_ins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('idTransactionIN');
        $table->date('buy_date');
        $table->string('id_Supplier')->unsigned();
        $table->string('id_DeviceType')->unsigned();
        $table->string('id_DeviceBrand')->unsigned();
        $table->string('device_name');
        $table->mediumText('device_name');
        $table->decimal('device_price', 11, 2);
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->decimal('sum_price', 15, 2);
        $table->mediumText('context');
        $table->timestamps();

        //Foreign Key
        $table->foreign('id_Supplier')->references('idSupplier')->on('suppliers')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_DeviceType')->references('idDeviceType')->on('device_types')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_DeviceBrand')->references('idDevicebrand')->on('device_brands')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

I get this error message

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You  have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `id_DeviceType`
>   varchar(255) unsigned not null, `id_DeviceBra' at line 1 (SQL: create
>   table`transaction_ins`(`id`bigint unsigned not null auto_increment
>   primary key,`idTransactionIN`varchar(255) not null,`buy_date`date
>   not null,`id_Supplier`varchar(255) unsigned not null,`
>   id_DeviceType`varchar(255) unsigned not null,`id_DeviceBrand
>   `varchar(255) unsigned not null,`device_name`varchar(255) not null,`
>   device_name`mediumtext not null,`device_price`decimal(11, 2) not
>   null,`amount`int not null,`sum_price`decimal(15, 2) not null,`
>   context`mediumtext not null,`created_at`timestamp null,`
>   updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: are the ids really strings? why not integers?

Comment: yeah its string i made a custom ids with alphabet in it.

Comment: First thing comes to mind when I hear an ID is an integer ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ so it's a bit weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have strings unsigned, that's meant for integers

just remove the unsigned modifier (if they are really strings)

```php
$table->string('id_Supplier');
$table->string('id_DeviceType');
$table->string('id_DeviceBrand');
```

Comment: the migration is happen the table created in database but then new error happen `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`, is it safe to change the data type from `string` to `integer` if my `unique id` have alphabet like `ABC0001`

Comment: I have to see your other tables to tell

Comment: and no it's not safe, integers can't have alphabetic characters in them

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387641/laravel-6-undefined-variable-value-only-error-in-the-first-time

Comment: Only one table `device_types` is there and it seems okay

Comment: Please edit the question and add the table migration classes for `suppliers` and `device_brands` if that's not much to ask

Answer (score 0):

Change **string** data type to **integer** data type for the ones you labeled as unsigned